# Build application (that requires libraries built with older MinGW) with newer MinGW?

Tags: c++, cmake, makefile, g++, mingw-w64

I used MinGW v8 to build a C++ library. That library dynamically links to standard C++ libraries `libgcc_s_seh-1.dll`, `libstdc++-6.dll`, and `libwinpthread-1.dll` which are included with MinGW.

Now I am trying to build another C++ application using a newer version of MinGW v11. The application is dynamically linked to the library I built previously. The application also dynamically links to standard C++ libraries `libgcc_s_seh-1.dll`, `libstdc++-6.dll`, and `libwinpthread-1.dll`.

The issue now is that the library requires those same files from v8 and the application requires those files from v11. I get a different error at runtime depending on which version I include.

I am wondering, how does one normally go about this ? Does the library and application need to be built with the same compiler version to avoid conflicts or is there something I am missing in my understanding ? Thanks.

Error when using v8 files
[image: Error when using v8 files]

Error when using v11 files
[image]

Comment: Yes, you need to use a single runtime library, I don't think mingw offers any compatibility between versions

Comment: A library built against an older runtime generally should work with a newer runtime. At least that's how gcc on platforms that aren't Windows works. Which errors are you getting?

Comment: Rebuild the libraries with the new tool-chain.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I have attached the errors in the OP. What about using static linking on the main application ?

Comment: The first error is expected. You cannot use an old libstdc++ with a newer executable. The second error is a known problem, there are many bug reports but I don't know of a solution. The function in question resides in libsupc++.a. I think the problem is that it is not exported so the dll cannot find it. Perhaps you can export it from the executable, not sure what the exact procedure would be.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike C, C++ does not normally offer a stable ABI for your functions. Thus, if you try to link two C++ libraries built with different toolchains, there is a good chance that you would get linker errors.

The quickest solution is to recompile the older library, if you still have the source code. If you want ABI stability, you can maintain a set of `extern "C"` wrappers  around your C++ code alongside them, so you don't need to worry about linking issues.

Comment: This is simply not true. The GCC toolchain and the LLVM toolchain are as stable (backwards-compatible) as humanly possible. MSVC toolchain is not, bit MSVC is hardly all of C++.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I haven't been able to find anywhere that the mingw libstdc++ ABI provides any stability guarantees, the number of people posting issues here with crashes or other strange behaviour when mixing mingw versions suggests there isn't much stability. Multiple different distributions and considerations of mingw possibly doesn't help. MSVC has had a stable ABI since 2015

Comment: @AlanBirtles "the number of people posting issues here with crashes or other strange behaviour when mixing mingw versions suggests there isn't much stability." Programmers produce bugs, news at 11. Nobody can give you any guarantee of anything, but [the documented intent is a stable ABI](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html), and it works this way most of the time. "MSVC has had a stable ABI since 2015" Good to know, I was out of the loop with MSVC.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI that documentation is for gcc, not mingw though, it's very Linux centric and uses Linux features and makes no mention of mingw or windows

Comment: MinGW is a build of gcc and related tools for Windows. MinGW-specific bugs go to the general GCC bugzilla. If there is documentation with specific guarantees or caveats or whatever about MinGW, use it, otherwise GCC documentation applies as far as I'm concerned.